# Quotients of Products of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A\le B\le G$ with $A\trianglelefteq B$ and let $N\trianglelefteq G$. By the lattice isomorphism theorem, we know $$\frac{NA}{N}\trianglelefteq\frac{NB}{N},$$ so we can take the quotient and rewrite it with the third isomorphism theorem: $$\frac{NB/N}{NA/N}\cong\frac{NB}{NA}.$$ What can we say about $\frac{NB}{NA}$ in relation to $\frac{B}{A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{NB}{NA}
=
\frac{NAB}{NA}
\simeq
\frac{B}{NA\cap B}
\simeq
\frac{B/A}{(NA\cap B)/A}
$$
and so $NB/NA$ is a quotient of $B/A$.

Comment: this is wrong take $N=G$

Comment: Both sides seem trivial to me.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is exactly what I was looking for